# Duplicating form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, duplicates

I've been trying to find a way to duplicate this form and its input fields for a couple of days. I've tried using code that I've found [here](http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html) but to no avail. How do I duplicate this form?

HTML

```
<form action="dilemman.php" method="post" class="copy" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Video: <br>
    <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video"></textarea>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="copy" rel=".form">Duplicate form</a>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false">remove</a>';
$('a.copy').relCopy({limit: 5, append: removeLink});
```

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Duplicate form</button>
```

js:

```
 function myFunction() {
        var elmnt = document.getElementById("formid");
        var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(cln);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however new form that is duplicated shows only for a second then disapears instantly. How do I prevent this?

Comment: How do I prevent the form from disapearing? @Nero

Answer (score 1):

you can use only jquery, do not need to use relCopy..

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/jWEYeB

```
var cp = $('form.copy').html();
$('a.copy').on('click', function(){
    $('form.copy').append( cp );
})
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the `relCopy` docs says that you have to target your form with the `rel` attribute in the `a` element, which you are not.

`<form action="dilemman.php" method="post" class="copy"`

`<a href="#" class="copy" rel=".form">Duplicate form</a>`

Change to

`<form action="dilemman.php" method="post"`**`class="form"`**

`<a href="#" class="copy" rel=".form">Duplicate form</a>`